# Will these both code do the same thing?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
var1 db 20

;--------code 1-------
 lea bx, var1
mov byte ptr[bx],40

;--------code 2-------
lea bx,var1
mov [bx], 40
```

is this both above are valid ?  and same ? if yes then why do we use byte ptr?

Comment: _"if we wanted to just change byte we can take bl"_ You mean `mov [bl],40`? That's not valid, and even if it was it wouldn't have the same meaning.

Comment: _"Will these both code do the same thing?"_ Assemble it and see what happens. Some assemblers might treat them the same, and some might not. The size of the immediate 40 is not known, which is why `byte ptr` is used.

Comment: Using `byte ptr` explicitly says to move a *byte*, otherwise the assembler have to deduce the size of the data being moved and it might assume the wrong size (like a word, 16 bits) which will be wrong in your case.

Comment: there are many encodings for mov, when memory is the desitnation, it can be byte, word, etc.  So there is maybe a default for each assembler, but if you want to specifically control the size of the move...you need to be specific.  You might get lucky today, but in the long run from one assembler to another or version to another, your luck will run out.

Comment: On top of the other comments: Your syntax suggests _MASM_ or _TASM_ (This doesn't apply to any assemblers that aren't _MASM_ compatible, and most aren't). This applies to _MASM/TASM_: Both these assemblers keep track of the data type used to define variables. `var1` was defined as a `byte` with the `var1 db 20`.If you use the variable directly as part of the addressing, the assembler can also deduce the size based on its knowledge of the type. This instruction would work: `mov var1, 40` and would have been same as `mov byte ptr [var1], 40`

Answer (score 2):

No, they aren't.

The first piece of code includes a size specifier: `byte ptr`. Without this, there is nothing to give the assembler a hint as to the size of the source and destination. While you *may* find that under *some* circumstances (various directives controlling the overall assembly of the code, for instance) that they perform the same way, this is not to be relied upon.

What may seem ambiguous is that you could have written this as `mov var1, 40` without a size specifier. However, if you were to disassemble the code produced, you would find that the assembler took care of matters behind the scene using the hint from the `var1 db` line, which indicates that this is a byte rather than a word, dword, etc. In other words, the assembler would have actually produced:

```
mov byte ptr [var1], 40
```